# Meaning of multiple added platform tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Using OS tags for questions to distinguish whether a software

- should be available on **all** named platforms (for a inter-platform usecase) or
- should be available on just **any** platform

seems difficult. Furthermore browsing or search queries like

```
[windows] hasaccepted:yes
```

may not bring up the answers one is looking for. So, do we have / need a rule for the usage multiple platform tags. Possibilities:

- <kbd>AND</kbd> interpretation
- <kbd>OR</kbd> interpretation
- introduction of another tag to distiguish
- discourage

Answer (score 1):

There is a [cross-platform](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform) tag, which I think should be encouraged for questions about software that needs to work on more than one platform (surely on more than two).

Comment: I don't like [tag:cross-platform] because it's too vague. Does it mean “must run on Android, iOS and Windows/ARM”? Or “must run on Linux, OSX and Windows/PC”?

Comment: @Gilles: I don't think any reasonable number of tags can discriminate all those distinctions.  So we expect to find the finer requirements stated in the Question, with tags that are chosen for improved search.  Cross-platform is for software that needs to run on multiple platforms (an AND requirement), in the OP's term.

Comment: But what's the point of a tag that doesn't have a consistent meaning? Who's going to subscribe or ignore [tag:cross-platform]? How useful would it be in a search, since you'd also have to search for the platforms you're interested in anyway?

Comment: @Gilles its very useful if you search on something that has to run on "all machines in my company" so you are looking for solutions that work on at least two platforms.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer What's the point if I'm looking for something that runs on Linux and Windows but the tag also points to things that run on Android and iOS? I'll be searching for “Linux” and “Windows” anyway.

Comment: @Gilles No. Because the OSs that have been requested could have been "osx" and "windows" and thous you won't find it with "linux" AND "windows". Or you use the system that will be the new fad in 2 years and look for programs that are "cross-platform" because the chance that they support $new_system are higher than any single plattform system. Or you don't know which systems it must support (because your company has a "bring your own device" policy) and are looking for solutions that support the most platforms. (I can continue this list, shall I?)

Comment: Lots of programs are described as “cross-platform” even though they don't run on any of the “new fad” systems. Like, say, Flash, which doesn't even run on several of today's most popular platforms and yet is described as cross-platform.